# How to instantiate empty array of object which is a member field of another object?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular 4 app. In the TS file, I have the following data-type:

```
 testBody: {
        test_category: string,
        test_instruction: string,
        test_duration: string,
        test_name: string,
        test_class: string,
        test_language: string,
        test_exam: string,
        test_board: string,
        client_id: string,
        program_id: string,
        test_visibility: number,
        test_sections_data: [
            {
                section_name: string,
                section_max_marks: number,
                section_cut_off: number,
                section_topper_marks: number,
                section_number_of_questions: number
            }]
    }
```

Now, I want to instantiate an empty `testBody` object which can be binded with the html code. For that I do following in the controller class:

```
...
 constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private route: ActivatedRoute, private dragulaService: DragulaService, private http: HttpClient) {
        const bag: any = this.dragulaService.find('bag-task1');
        ...
        this.testBody = {
            test_category: '',
            test_instruction: '',
            test_duration: '',
            test_name: '',
            test_class: '',
            test_language: '',
            test_exam: '',
            test_board: '',
            client_id: allGlobals.client_id,
            program_id: this.program_id,
            test_visibility: null,
            test_sections_data: null
        };
       ...
    }
```

The problem is how to intialize empty array of `test_sections_data`? I have `tried test_sections_data: []` also but its not working.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: `test_sections_data` is not getting initialised as an empty array

Comment: What is the current behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

A good practice would be to add `TestBody` and `TestSectionData` interfaces:

https://jsfiddle.net/2s9sav9m/1/

Then you're able to set the default value to [] and push to it, or reset it, as needed, while keeping consistency of data.

You can also make `test_sections_data` optional by adding a `?` to the interface:

```
TestBody {
    ...
    test_sections_data?: TestSectionData[]
    ...
}
```

if you want the value to be falsy by default.

Hopefully this makes sense / helps!